# How to retrieve data form Nested relationship without using loop

Tags: laravel

With the help of post model i want to show the data of category model.

i have applied the nested relationship.
For that i have to use foreach loop in the blade file.
Because of this the data are showing twice.

I have tried using Nested Loop

```
 $data['details']= PostAd::with(['category.child.children'])->where('id',$id)->first();
```

```
 @foreach($details->category->child as $c)
     @foreach($c->children as $d)

      @if($d->category_type == 'mobiles')
        @include('Frontend.pages.particular.mobileparticular')
      @elseif ($d->category_type == 'clothing')
        @include('Frontend.pages.particular.clothparticular')
      @elseif ($d->category_type == 'Cars')
        @include('Frontend.pages.particular.carparticular')
      @elseif ($d->category_type == 'motorcycle')
        @include('Frontend.pages.particular.carparticular')  
      @elseif ($d->category_type == 'Printer and Scanner')
       @include('Frontend.pages.particular.equipmentparticular') 
      @endif
       @endforeach
       @endforeach
```

So, Because of foreach loop my data are being shown twice.

How to retrieve data from nested relationship without using loop.

Relations
Category Model

```
public function postads()
{
   return $this->hasOne(PostAd::class)->where('markassold',0);
}
```

PostAd Model

```
public function category()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id');
}
```

Comment: and did you try to delete the 2nd foreach loop?

 `@foreach($details->category->child->children as $c)`

Comment: if you are using `first()` then you don't need to use foreach

Comment: `child` is a 1:1 relation? if so @Kusy solution is correct, with a foreach you're iterating `child` attributes

Comment: @Kusy Yes, it doesn't work that way . I have to use foreach loop after the ->child

Comment: @A4family ok, so that's not 1:1 relation. Could you please share the relation?

Comment: They are one to one relation

Comment: @ZainFarooq I need to use for nested relationship

Comment: @IlGala Yes it is a 1:1 relation.